# accentuation treatment in Mime on the Domino

Tags: web-services, lotus-domino, mime

I am creating a web service in java in Domino that from a stream that represents a file and its name, a notes document is created, the stream is transformed into a file and attached to the document. The problem is that for name of files with accentuation occurs the truncation of letters with accentuation. I have tried several alternatives to handle this exception, but none have had the desired effect. Has anyone ever had this problem? The code snippet where the attachment is named follows.

```
header.setHeaderVal("attachment; filename=\""+nomeArq+"\"");
```

Comment: Take a look at the question and answers here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http. Your question refers to a web service rather than an HTML page, and the question I linked is referring to a content-disposition header rather than an attachment header, but I believe the principles must be the same: You will probably have to use the % encoding for byte values and maybe use the *=UTF-8'' syntax. Since you are writing in Java, at least I don't think you need to worry about converting LMBCS to Unicode.

Comment: I read the link, I tried the various tips, but I did not succeed. The context mentioned in the link governs somewhat the purpose, since the document with the attachment is seen through the client. I have chosen the alternative to replace the accented characters.